# Vue3: Cannot find module './assets/logo.png' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I made the simplest project using

```
vue create testtype3
```

command:

[image]

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">

  <img :src="MyIcon" />

</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import MyIcon from './assets/logo.png';


export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {


  },

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    return  {
      MyIcon
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

**main.ts**:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**index.d.ts**:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**babel.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "testtype3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**vue.config.js**:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

The `App` displays a logo in two ways: passing a path String to an `img` and by passing an imported `MyLogo` to an `img`. However, I get an error for the second approach:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module './assets/logo.png' or its corresponding type declarations.
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import MyIcon from './assets/logo.png';
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Removing the `MyIcon` import and the `img` element that uses `MyIcon` results in `npm run serve` running without problems.

I made a `types` folder in the root directory and created a `index.d.ts` there, however the error still persists.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you migrate the build system to Vite. The Vue CLI is now deprecated

Comment: See here for the Vue CLI instructions for what you're trying to do though https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports

Comment: @Phil Thank you for the advice. I migrated the project to `Vite` and now it works. I'll leave the question open, however, as someone might encounter the same issue without having an ability to migrate

Comment: The original question is answered by following the documentation for Vue CLI. Basically you use `require()` or just a regular `src` attribute

Answer (score 1):

you should edit index.d.ts to this:

```
declare module '*.png' {
  const value: string;
  export = value;
}
```

also you should add a line to tsconfig.json so it should look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    // add this line
    "types/index.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```